# Parse HTML page in Java

Tags: java, html, xml, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I'm parsing this page segment:

```
<tr valign="middle">
   <td class="inner"><span style=""><span class="" title=""></span> 2  <span class="icon ok" title="Verified"></span> </span><span class="icon cat_tv" title="Video » TV" style="bottom:-2;"></span> <a href="/VALUE.html" style="line-height:1.4em;">VALUE</a> </td>
   <td width="1%" align="center" nowrap="nowrap" class="small inner" >VALUE</td>
   <td width="1%" align="right" nowrap="nowrap" class="small inner" >VALUE</td>
   <td width="1%" align="center" nowrap="nowrap" class="small inner" >VALUE</td>
</tr>
```

I have this segment in variable tv: `HtmlElement tv = tr.get(i);`

I read tag `<a href="/VALUE.html" style="line-height:1.4em;">VALUE</a>` in this way:

```
HtmlElement a = tv.getElementsByTagName("a").get(0);        
object.name.value(a.getTextContent());

url = a.getAttribute("href");
object.url_detail.value(myBase + url);
```

How can I read only VALUE field of the other `<td>....</td>` sections?

Comment: What framework are you using for the parsing?

Comment: maybe using `tv.getElementsByTagName("td")` and looping over the result and getting the text content using `getTextContent()` ? did you try that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using [XPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html), which is the recommended way of parsing XML/HTML

Reference: [How to read XML using XPath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java)

Also take a look at this question: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

**Update**

If I understood correctly, you need the "VALUE" from each td, right?
If so, your XPath would something like this:

```
//td[@class="small inner"]/text()
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try a wonderful java package [**jsoup**](http://jsoup.org/).
UPDATE: using the package, you can solve the problem like this:

```
    String html = "<tr valign=\"middle\">"
            + "   <td class=\"inner\">"
            + "   <span style=\"\"><span class=\"\" title=\"\"></span> 2  <span class=\"icon ok\" title=\"Verified\"></span> </span><span class=\"icon cat_tv\" title=\"Video » TV\" style=\"bottom:-2;\"></span>"
            + "   <a href=\"/VALUE.html\" style=\"line-height:1.4em;\">VALUE</a> "
            + "   </td>"
            + "   <td width=\"1%\" align=\"center\" nowrap=\"nowrap\" class=\"small inner\" >VALUE</td>"
            + "   <td width=\"1%\" align=\"right\" nowrap=\"nowrap\" class=\"small inner\" >VALUE</td>"
            + "   <td width=\"1%\" align=\"center\" nowrap=\"nowrap\" class=\"small inner\" >VALUE</td>"
            + "</tr>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
    Elements labelPLine = doc.select("a[href]");
    System.out.println("value 1:" + labelPLine.text());

    Elements labelPLine2 = doc.select("td[width=1%");
    Iterator<Element> it = labelPLine2.iterator();
    int n = 2;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("value " + (n++) + ":" + it.next().text());
    }
```

The result would be:

```
value 1:VALUE
value 2:VALUE
value 3:VALUE
value 4:VALUE
```

Comment: You should say how you could solve the problem using jsoup. Otherwise this is a non-answer and should just have been a comment.